# Uninstall system app failed using 'adb shell pm uninstall'

Tags: adb, uninstallation

I attempted to force uninstall in ADB, but failed:

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall -k org.openintents.filemanager
$ adb shell pm list packages -f | grep -i manager
package:/system/app/FileManager.apk=org.openintents.filemanager
```

What went wrong here? What can I do?

I used the internal application manager and there isn't an option to delete it.

Comment: When manually deleting application from /system remember to delete their corresponding data folder in /data/data/«identifier» There is also a track of the previous apk signature in /data/system/packages.xml that can prevent a reinstall of a rebuilt package with a different key.

Answer (score 21):

Well, since the `FileManager.apk` package resides in a `/system/app/` directory it is a system app. So the general way to remove it is:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
rm -rf /system/app/FileManager.apk
rm -rf /data/data/org.openintents.filemanager
mount -o ro,remount /system
exit
exit
```

Comment: When I run `mount -o ro,remount /system`, I get an error: **Device or resource busy**

Comment: @IgorG. I was able to resolve that by answering a prompt on the actual device.

Comment: @AlexB Actually, no prompt occurs.  This is a custom bootlegged phone, I guess.

Comment: Worked for me, Make sure the device has root access.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit**: when I saw the comment to CommonsWare answer I did not realize it was the same as the asker... anyways, a little explanation may be useful for somebody.

As yourself commented, the easiest way to uninstall a system app is plainly to delete the `.apk` file. The `adb install` / `adb uninstall` commands are useful for **regular apps, not system apps**. Since this apk is located in `/system/app`, `adb uninstall` will not remove it.

You can use the command suggested (`rm /system/app/YourApp.apk`), but before the `/system` folder need to have write access. You will need to see how to `remount` `/system` in your specific device, try searchig for "`android remount +rw /system`" and your device).

Alternatively, you may use any app that can do both deletion and remounting and has root access, such as **Root Explorer** and **Astro**

Comment: thanks aleadam... plot thickens because the rm that i did removed the apk but, maybe, not the cache.. Im unable to install from the market .. that fails .. looks like i either have to clear the dalvik cache or just revert the entire ROM to a backup image... install at cmd line with adb ==> [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE] ... unable to use market to download install ... get "installation error incompatible update" ... im on a custom rom and have a backup thats 2 weeks old and i may just revert to that.

Comment: [link](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/19216-uninstalling-file-manager/)  what i should have done is in the 2nd post on this thread

Answer (score 1):

The '`Failure`' problem has more to do with the adb shell appending a DOS line ending ^M (on CentOS Linux anyway).  Put the list of applications to uninstall in a file and copy to the android device directly.

```
root@android:/root # dos2unix list-of-apps-to-uninstall.txt     
root@android:/root # for f in `cat list-of-apps-to-uninstall.txt` ; do echo $f; pm uninstall $f; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tapemaster has made a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047930/how-to-uninstall-own-app-from-system-app#11686570) which demonstrates the necessary trick.

Do this:

1.  Install `adb` on your computer.

2.  Root your phone.

3.  Enter these commands into your computer:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
rm /system/app/UnwantedApp*
pm uninstall org.unwantedapp
exit
exit
```

The third command remounts `/system` read-write.  The fourth command deletes the app's `.apk` and/or `.odex` files.  The fifth command finishes the uninstallation.

In my experience:  If you have already entered the the fourth command, then the fifth command will return Success.  Otherwise, the fifth command will return Failure.

When entering the above commands, you must replace `UnwantedApp` with the app's real filename (without the extension), and `org.unwantedapp` with the app's real Java package name.

Comment: Can you justify the existence of your answer, when the majority of the content as well as the essence is already covered in an [existing answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/96479/96277)?

Comment: @Firelord: 1. When "pm uninstall" reports "Success", it gives users confirmation which reassures them that they've done everything right. Sadly, `rm -rf /data/data/org.openintents.filemanager` doesn't provide such confirmation. 2. I speculate that `pm uninstall` might do more than just removing the app's data directory even in current Android versions.  And definitely it might do more in Android versions which will be released a decade from now. Really, `pm uninstall` is the Right Way to uninstall packages.  I urge you to choose the Right Way instead of trying to kludge things yourself.