# Cannot uninstall an app from adb

Tags: applications, adb, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall an app which came to me with the phone ( an app for senior users - sort of launcher).

My device is : LG L70
Android version : 4.4.2
However I cannot uninstall it from the phone by dragging it from app screen. I've tried to uninstall it from the adb:

```
adb uninstall "package name"
```

but I get:

```
Failure
```

as a response.

When I list all my aps from the adb:

```
adb shell 'pm list packages -f'
```

I cannot find the app on the list.
The only way that helped me to discover the package name(in order to uninstall it) is by using "System Info for Android" app...

What can be done in order to remove this annoying app?

I've rooted the device and did a factory reset...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is a system app hence ADB or Package manager won't give you any option to remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall system app failed using 'adb shell pm uninstall'](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12405/uninstall-system-app-failed-using-adb-shell-pm-uninstall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to uninstall it from adb? If you have a rooted phone you can remove it from the device itself. There are a lot of apps that you can do this that are in the playstore. I personally use " system app remover (ROOT)". Just search for the app name and uninstall it.

PS: Did you try ading "su" at the begining of the command to use root?

Comment: Adding su won't help ADB to remove a system app. Being a system app grants it protection from removal.

Comment: I've finally succeeded to uninstall the app with kingoroot... Thanks

Answer (score -1):

do `adb shell uninstall`, that should work.

Comment: *uninstall: inaccessible or not found*