# Cannot disable OEM app

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, root-access, settings, malware

My new [Jasper](http://www.imei.info/phonedatabase/101700-zte-jasper-lte-z718tl/) phone has a persistent app from the original manufacture which keeps popping up.  Without [rooting](http://androidbiits.com/root-tracfone-zte-jasper-z718tl-easily/) the phone, how can I disable or remove this app?  Dragging it to "remove" doesn't persist as the app comes back on its own.

Can I get back to some stock version without the OEM apps?

*I have already disabled the app, but it keeps respawning so that the icon populates to the home screen.*

Comment: "Can I get back to some stock version without the OEM apps" - I do not know what you asking. Can you update the question with what app you are trying to remove/disable and what you would prefer to use?

Comment: If you managed to deinstall or disable the app but it "returns" there must be a second app or service checking the app and reinstalling/reactivating it.

Answer (score 1):

Apps are disabled in Settings - Apps...

Go to your Settings - Apps and press the 3-dot menu button and Show System, find the app in question and tap it open in the list, then select Disable. If there is no Disable option, then the app is set by the OEM to not be able to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disable it by touching and holding the app on your Home Screen and dragging over to the 'App info' button and clicking on disable. If the 'disable' button is nonexistent or is greyed out, then rooting the device will be the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the adb solution i.E [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12405/uninstall-system-app-failed-using-adb-shell-pm-uninstall) to remove without root. Or you could get a stock firmware form the zte website an flash it with odin. But i could not find this model at zte nor [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/zte).

Comment: ODIN is only for Samsung devices... It doesn't work on ANY other phones. ZTE phones use either fastboot or SD card update to flash stock firmware, and only a few select models (like Axon) are even capable, others models need to be sent in to the manufacturer for reflashing if there is an issue as ZTE doesn't release many factory firmware packages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

1. Connect device via ADB
2. Go to ADB shell

   ```
   adb shell
   ```
3. Find your target app by listing all the apps

   ```
   pm list packages
   ```
4. Remove app like this

   ```
   pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.inputdevices
   ```