# Consequences of removing Launcher3's APK (com.android.launcher3)

Tags: root-access, 5.1-lollipop, launcher

I have a rooted tablet with my own custom launcher which is already the default launcher. Are their any side effects if I delete the Launcher3's APK (com.android.launcher3) which is stored in `/system/app/Launcher3/Launcher3.apk?`

My device is chinese custom tablet with an RK3288 procesor, Android 5.1.1.

Comment: Apart from having issues after a factory reset (no launcher then, and neither ADB nor network available to install any)? I don't think so. But what should be the advantage of removing it?

Comment: Actually I added my launcher to `/system/priv-app/` so that is also not a problem because my own launcher will start after factory settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see any issue with that. Though since you're rooted you can probably do it more cleanly with ADB as seen [in this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12405/uninstall-system-app-failed-using-adb-shell-pm-uninstall). If that doesn't work follow the manual delete steps listed there too.

Comment: can you add little bit more information, as is there anything besides the Launcher3 activity in that APK? As an example, Samsung's TouchWiz comes with multiple activities, not just the launcher.