# Cant uninstall but device admistrative is empty

Tags: applications, permissions, uninstallation, exchange, device-administrator

I have an app which was downloaded by pre-owner of the phone and I can't uninstall.That app uses all permissions and I cant change its permissions nor uninstall.Im using samsung galaxy A8 star (android 10 +)

Comment: Have you performed a factory reset before starting to use the phone?

Comment: No I don't...later I have factory reset still it's same

Comment: Then the device is most likely unlocked/rooted and the app has been installed as system app.

Comment: Is there any way to uninstall??

Comment: If the app is installed as system app you have to manually delete the apk via adb as shown here: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12405/2241 Warning: The file name is not the app package name, thus make sure you are deleting the correct file, otherwise the device may fail to boot. In general I would recommend to reset the whole device by installing a fresh system firmware but you need to get the exactly matching firmware for your device and region.